# Shell Script Producing Strange File Type with Interpunct

Tags: command-line, scripts, file-format

I am new to Linux - trying to run a set of commands using a shell script. The commands are from the Neper software package but I am pretty certain the issue is with permissions of my shell script.  When I enter the commands line-by-line in the terminal I get the correct output but when I run the shell script, files are not generated correctly.

**Here is the shell script:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

neper -T -n 500 -domain "cube(1,1,0.5)" -morpho gg -morphooptistop eps=1e-2 -statseed x,y,z,w -o part1

awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' part1.stseed > part1.coo

awk '{print $4}' part1.stseed > part1.w

neper -T -n 100 -dim 2 -morpho gg -morphooptistop eps=1e-2 -statseed x,y,z,w -o part2

awk '{print $1,$2,0.6}' part2.stseed > part2.coo

awk '{print $4}' part2.stseed > part2.w

cat part1.coo part2.coo > coo

cat part1.w part2.w > w

neper -T -n 600 -morphooptiini "coo:file(coo),weight:file(w)" -o full

neper -V full.tess -print img
```

**Output:** Using the shell script, the `part1` and `part2` `.stseed` files are generated as extensionless files (0 kb). This then generates the error:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file 'X.stseed' for reading: No such file or directory.
```

Later on, the `.coo` and `.w` files are generated as `.coo·` and `.w·` files. Because of the added interpunct - the files are not recognized by latter code and again, the `No such file or directory` error shows up.

Any idea of what I am doing incorrectly is appreciated. I am running the shell scripts using `chmod` and have tried various modes and options.

Comment: I'd start by checking if your script has any non-printing trailing characters e.g. with `cat -A yourscript`

Comment: Also, where are these `.stseed` files created? I don't see them in the script, I only see you trying to read from them. Should tat first command perhaps be `neper ... -o part1.stseed`?
And remembre that extensions are just decorative in Linux. With very, very few exceptions, the extensions is just optional and irrelevant, it doesn't define the file type as is the case in Windows. So extensionless files are very rarely a problem.

Comment: Thank you both - the culprit turned out to be non-printing trailing characters.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was non-printing trailing characters [as suggested by steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491326/shell-script-producing-strange-file-type-with-interpunct/1491727#comment2612464_1491326).